# Undefined index name, while uploading image file in PHP. I am just testing this module for my project

Tags: php, html

***This is the error appearing on browser screen.***

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp64\www\roomdhundhoo\roomdhundho\owner\test.php on line 3
```

My ***HTML*** Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Image upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get image">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i am trying to upload file using ***$_FILES['pic']['name']*** function, it is showing that ***'name'*** index is not defined. 

 My ***PHP*** Code.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $file_name=$_FILES["pic"]["name"];
  }
?>
```

When i tried this code:-

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     $file_name = basename($_FILES['pic']['name']);
  }
?>
```

Same error is coming.

My code is successfully displaying file name directly. This means that PHP file is recognising that file has been submitted. 

***CODE***

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     $file_name = $_POST['pic'];
     echo $file_name;
  }
?>
```

***OUTPUT***

```
Screenshot (29).png
```

This is the file name, which i uploaded.

Comment: Does `var_dump($_FILES);` give you all correct details?

Comment: You have to check `$_FILE` not just `$_POST` since you might be submitting  the form without uploading a file.

Comment: As i said, i am just testing my code, so i properly upload the file. This code `<?php
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     $file_name = $_POST['pic'];
     echo $file_name;
  }
?>` is properly displaying the file name. That means file has been selected.

Comment: When i am checking `$_FILE` then it is returning false even i upload the file.